# Why does PHPStorm report that padding isn't allowed on a span element?

Tags: html, phpstorm, stylesheet

I have the following html code. The PHPStorm says attribute padding is not allowed here. How can I quickly fix this?

```
<span style="padding:10px 0;"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding works on `inline-block` and `block` level elements

or rather use a stylesheet:

```css
.padded{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: navajowhite;
}
```

```html
<span class="padded">I have a class!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Span elements are inline by default, and therefore don't have margin, padding, size, etc. Set it to `display: inline-block` or use a div.